# About open ssh latest version in ubuntu 16

Tags: networking

All could some one help me with the latest OPENSSH version for ubuntu 16 , we have 1.7.2.x openssh version, but still getting vulnerability scan report and as per that need to upgrade to latest version 1.8.x, So is that integrated with  ubuntu 16. Latest patching ?

Answer (score 5):

Ninety percent of vulnerability scanners go strictly by the version string returned by the OpenSSH libraries.  Unfortunately, they aren't smart and don't know what patches are on your system nor do they actually *test* for the presence of the vulnerabilities (because this can be destructive and dangerous on production systems).

OpenSSH currently has no unpatched CVEs in Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 according to the [Security Team's CVE Tracker](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/pkg/openssh.html).  [Ubuntu Security Notices](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=&details=OpenSSH) are issued for when there's patches being pushed out into the repositories' `-security` pocket.  (Note that this does not include currently embargoed issues - issues that are not yet public knowledge yet - nobody has any insight into those except the Security team)

If you have specific CVEs the vuln scan references you can look them up in the CVE tracker yourself [here](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-security/cve/) with the specific CVE identifier you're wanting to ID if you're patched from.

Chances are, though, if you are running OpenSSH Server `1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8` or later (at the time of this post) on Ubuntu 16.04 you are on the latest patch-set.  (You can verify this by looking at `apt-cache policy openssh-server` and looking at the "Installed" line for identifying the version you've got installed)

Just a tidbit, unless you pay for Ubuntu Advantage, 16.04 dies in just about six months for general support, so you should probably start thinking of upgrading from 16.04 sooner than later.